# Spring Boot REST API JPA nao funciona direito

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field usuarioRepository in com.julio.demo.DemoApplication required a bean of type 'com.julio.repositories.UsuarioRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.julio.repositories.UsuarioRepository' in your configuration.

Segue meu codigo:
'''

```
package com.julio.demo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import com.julio.domain.Usuario;
import com.julio.repositories.UsuarioRepository;

@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Usuario u1 = new Usuario(null, "julio", "julio", "123");
        Usuario u2 = new Usuario(null, "cesar", "cesar", "123");

        usuarioRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(u1,u2));
    
    }

}
```

'''

```
package com.julio.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.julio.domain.Usuario;

@Repository
public interface UsuarioRepository extends JpaRepository<Usuario, Integer>{

}
```